# Extract *specific* elements of a list column to new columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

In R, I know how to extract elements of a (named) list column into separate columns, provided they are the same length:

```
library(tidyverse)

tib1 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
                                 list(a = 3, b = 4, c = 5),
                                 list(a = 5, b = 6, c = 7)))
tib1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>       x y         
>   <int> <list>    
> 1     1 <list [3]>
> 2     2 <list [3]>
> 3     3 <list [3]>
> ```

```
bind_cols(tib1[1], bind_rows(tib1$y))
```

> ```
>     # A tibble: 3 x 4
>       x     a     b     c
>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1  1.00  2.00  3.00
> 2     2  3.00  4.00  5.00
> 3     3  5.00  6.00  7.00
> ```

The problem is once one of the elements in the lists is of different length (here `a`):

```
tib2 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(list(a = 1:2, b = 2, c = 3),
                                 list(a = 3:4, b = 4, c = 5),
                                 list(a = 5:6, b = 6, c = 7)))

bind_cols(tib2[1], bind_rows(tib2$y))
```

> `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 2 must be length 2, not 1`

Is there an elegant way to tell R to not include `a` in the extraction, or only include `b` and `c`, or to only include elements with the same length `l`? Hopefully in a "pipe-ish", "tidyverse-ish" way?

Expected result should keep `a` somehow, either simply by keeping the entire `y` field so I can access it in the future somehow:

```
tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(list(a = 1:2, b = 2, c = 3),
                         list(a = 3:4, b = 4, c = 5),
                         list(a = 5:6, b = 6, c = 7)),
       b = c(2, 4, 6),
       c = c(3, 5, 7))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>       x y              b     c
>   <int> <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1 <list [3]>  2.00  3.00
> 2     2 <list [3]>  4.00  5.00
> 3     3 <list [3]>  6.00  7.00
> ```

Or preferably as a new list column:

```
tibble(x = 1:3,
       a = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6),
       b = c(2, 4, 6),
       c = c(3, 5, 7))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>       x a             b     c
>   <int> <list>    <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1 <int [2]>  2.00  3.00
> 2     2 <int [2]>  4.00  5.00
> 3     3 <int [2]>  6.00  7.00
> ```

Comment: Maybe `transpose` first and then `unlist` if each `list` element contains only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `tidyverse` would be to `map` through the `list` column 'y', convert it to 'tibble', then `unnest` to expand the rows, and `summarise` the 'a' column as a `list` after grouping by the other columns

```
library(tidyverse)
tib2 %>%
    mutate(y = map(y, as_tibble)) %>%
    unnest %>% 
    group_by(x, b, c) %>% 
    summarise(a = list(a)) %>%
    select(x, a, b, c)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups: x, b [3]
#      x a             b     c
#   <int> <list>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 <int [2]>  2.00  3.00
#2     2 <int [2]>  4.00  5.00
#3     3 <int [2]>  6.00  7.00
```

Comment: Is there a way in the `group_by` to say `x` and everything else but `a`? Or everything but `a`? Suppose it's not just `b` and `c` it's more variables

Comment: @GioraSimchoni  You can change the group_by to `group_by_at(setdiff(names(.), "a"))`

Comment: That's great, I'm also adding `ungroup` at the end.

Comment: Got a few great answers. Will choose this one because it is the most "tidy", in the sense that it starts with `tib2` (as opposed to `transpose(tib2$y)`), then uses the simplest most readable flow IMO. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R solution as well,

```
dd <- data.frame(x = tib2$x, t(do.call(cbind, tib2$y)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   x    a b c
> 1 1 1, 2 2 3
> 2 2 3, 4 4 5
> 3 3 5, 6 6 7
> ```

Inspecting the structure, we see that all three columns are lists.

```
 str(dd)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 2
  ..$ : int  3 4
  ..$ : int  5 6
 $ b:List of 3
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 4
  ..$ : num 6
 $ c:List of 3
  ..$ : num 3
  ..$ : num 5
  ..$ : num 7
```

If you want to unlist `b` and `c`, then simply,

```
dd[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(dd[-c(1, 2)], unlist)
```

which gives the structure:

```
str(dd)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 2
  ..$ : int  3 4
  ..$ : int  5 6
 $ b: num  2 4 6
 $ c: num  3 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible approach:

```
transpose(tib2$y) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) if(all(lengths(x) == 1)) unlist(x, use.names = FALSE) else x) %>% 
  bind_cols(., tib2[1])
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   a             b     c     x
#   <list>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 <int [2]>    2.    3.     1
# 2 <int [2]>    4.    5.     2
# 3 <int [2]>    6.    7.     3
```

---

Sticking with the "tidyverse", I guess the approach would be:

```
transpose(tib2$y) %>% 
  map_if(~ all(lengths(.) == 1), unlist) %>%
  bind_cols(., tib2[1])
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   a             b     c     x
#   <list>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 <int [2]>    2.    3.     1
# 2 <int [2]>    4.    5.     2
# 3 <int [2]>    6.    7.     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse`-option:

```
library(tidyverse)

tib2 %>% 
  mutate(a = map(y, ~ .x[lengths(.x) > 1])) %>% 
  bind_cols(., map_dfr(.$y, ~ .x[lengths(.x) == 1])) %>% 
  select(-y)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      x a              b     c
  <int> <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 <list [1]>  2.00  3.00
2     2 <list [1]>  4.00  5.00
3     3 <list [1]>  6.00  7.00
```

Comment: Not pretty, but maybe you should add something that would do the following: `mutate(a = map(y, ~ unlist(.x[lengths(.x) > 1], recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)))`

Comment: I guess `mutate(a = purrr::flatten(map(y, ~ .x[lengths(.x) > 1])))` should do it, right?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 yep, different ways to achieve that;  `map(y, ~ .x[lengths(.x) > 1][[1]])` works also

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` solution:

```
short <- which(lengths(tib2$y[[1]]) == 1)    
long <- setdiff(seq_along(tib2$y[[1]]),short) 
tib3 <- tib2 %>%
  mutate(long = map(y,~.[long])) %>%
  mutate(short = map(y,~.[short]))

bind_cols(tib2,tib3["long"], bind_rows(tib3$short))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#       x          y       long     b     c
#   <int>     <list>     <list> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 <list [3]> <list [1]>     2     3
# 2     2 <list [3]> <list [1]>     4     5
# 3     3 <list [3]> <list [1]>     6     7
```